# How Can I submit multiple jobs in Spark Standalone cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Machine with Apache Spark. Machine is `64GB RAM 16 Cores`.

My Objective in each spark job

```
1. Download a gz file from a remote server
2. Extract gz to get csv file (1GB max)
3. Process csv file in spark and save some stats.
```

Currently I am submitting one job for each file received by doing following

```
./spark-submit --class ClassName --executor-cores 14 --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g jar_path
```

And wait for this job to complete and then start new job for new file.

Now I want to utilise 64GB RAM by running multiple jobs in parallel.

I can assign 4g RAM to each job and want to queue my jobs when there are enough jobs already running.

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you read all the files based on some predicate(say "Timestamp")? Even if you wish to assign the entire 64GB of memory to your job, if the execution plan generated by spark does not need the entire 64 gigs, the remaining memory would not be used in any case. If this is not what you are looking for, can you edit your question and add more details about your requirement?

Comment: @YayatiSule Files are coming in realtime. I can not read all files at once as I have to store stats file wise. I just don't want to waste memory and cores by processing only one file at a time.

Comment: even if that is the case, you can try to allot a higher memory to your executors and driver, but in the end the memory and core usage is governed by Spark's final execution plan which it generates at Runtime. Also your OS processes would require some amount of RAM to function. So you would never be able to completely utilize your CPU cores and RAM for a Single Spark process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49250238/5742662 Please refer to this answer of mine if you need some additional clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You should submit multiple jobs from different threads:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application

and configure pool properties (set schedulingMode to FAIR):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuring-pool-properties

From Spark Doc:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#resource-scheduling:

> The standalone cluster mode currently only supports a simple FIFO
>   scheduler across applications. However, to allow multiple concurrent
>   users, you can control the maximum number of resources each
>   application will use. By default, it will acquire all cores in the
>   cluster, which only makes sense if you just run one application at a
>   time. You can cap the number of cores by setting spark.cores.max ...

By default, it utilise all the resources for one single job.We need to define the resources so that their will be space to run other job as well.Below is the command you can use to submit spark job.

```
bin/spark-submit --class classname --master spark://hjvm1:6066 --deploy-mode cluster  --driver-memory 500M --conf spark.executor.memory=1g --conf spark.cores.max=1 /data/test.jar
```